# Do my buttons randomly malfunction because I've overloaded handler?

Tags: java, android, button, handler

I've made a simple whack-a-mole game with nine buttons.  The buttons start off black.  If they are pressed while black, a mistake is recorded.  The buttons will randomly flash either pale blue or dark blue.  They need to be pressed once while pale blue to record a score.  When dark blue, they need to be pressed twice.

When the buttons are working normally, they will record a point, make a chime sound and turn black when pressed the correct amount of times.

For the duration of a game, one of the nine buttons will randomly malfunction.  It will record mistakes, but not points (nor will they make a sound or turn black).

I can't figure out why this is.  If I end the game and reload it, the button will work fine again, but some other button will malfunction.

I thought maybe I should have used a button listener instead of onClick, so I changed the code and that didn't fix the problem.

My next guess was that I was putting too many threads on one handler.  I've now split 10 threads across three handlers, but that hasn't fixed the problem either.

The message I get in logcat when I press on the malfunctioning button is:

ViewPostIme pointer 0
ViewPostIme pointer 1

Does anyone know why the buttons randomly malfunction?

Thanks

This is the code for each button

```
    button9.setOnClickListener( new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (isFlashing9.get()) {
                clicked9++;
                 //code for when button pressed for correct number of times
                if (clicked9 == req9) {
                    isFlashing9.set(false);
                    button9.setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb(0, 0, 0));
                    streak++;
                    correct();
                    if (streak > bestScore) {
                        bestScore = streak;
                        best.setText("HI SCORE \n " + bestScore);
                        saveData();
                    }
                    currentStreak.setText("SCORE\n" + streak);

                    clicked9 = 0;

                }
            } else {
                playError(); //play error sound
                mistakesSO++;
                mistakes.setText("MISTAKES \n" + mistakesSO);
                if (mistakesSO == 3) {
                }
            }           
 }
    });
```

This is the runnable to change the button colour:

```
     public Runnable B9 = new Runnable() {
    
            public void run() {
                 ender9++;
                timerInt9++;
                if (timerInt9 % 10 == 1) {
                   
                    int colour = ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(1, 3); // sets button colour
                    if (colour == 1) {
                        button9.setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb(78, 162, 245));
                        req9 = 1; // sets number of button presses required
                        isFlashing9.set(true);
                    } else {
                        button9.setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb(56, 98, 173));
                        req9 = 2; // sets number of button presses required
                        isFlashing9.set(true);
                    }
                }
                if (timerInt9 % 10 == 3) {
                    button9.setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb(0, 0, 0)); // resets button to black after it has flashed for 2 seconds.  
                    isFlashing9.set(false);
                    timerInt9 = 110;
                }
                handler3.postDelayed(this, 1000);
                if (ender9 >= 3) {
                    handler3.removeCallbacks(this);
                    ender9=0;
                }
    
            }
        };
```

This is the runnable to choose which button flashes:

```
public Runnable ButtonChooser = new Runnable() {

    public void run() {
          // sets random time between buttons flashing
        int time = ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(100, 600);

        //picks the next button to flash
        int which = ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(1, 10);
        if (which ==1){
            if(!isFlashing1.get())handler.postDelayed(B1, 0);
        }
        if (which ==2){
            if(!isFlashing2.get())handler.postDelayed(B2, 0);
        }
        if (which ==3){
            if(!isFlashing3.get())handler.postDelayed(B3, 0);
        }
        if (which ==4){
            if(!isFlashing4.get()) handler2.postDelayed(B4, 0);
        }
        if (which ==5){
            if(!isFlashing5.get())handler2.postDelayed(B5, 0);
        }
        if (which ==6){
            if(!isFlashing6.get())handler2.postDelayed(B6, 0);
        }
        if (which ==7){
            if(!isFlashing7.get())handler3.postDelayed(B7, 0);
        }
        if (which ==8){
            if(!isFlashing8.get())handler3.postDelayed(B8, 0);
        }
        if (which ==9){
            if(!isFlashing9.get())handler3.postDelayed(B9, 0);
        }
        handler.postDelayed(this, time);

    }
};
```

Comment: I added `Java` tag. Please replace if my guess is wrong.

Comment: Thanks.  I should have mentioned it was java

Comment: It's probably a threading problem.  Your button press code runs on the UI thread,  What thread is the rest of your code running on?  Any checks to state should occur on the same thread they change, or the variables need a semaphore to protect them.

Comment: Everything used to run on the one handler that was created in the main thread.  Now the button chooser and buttons 1-3 run on handler.  Buttons 4-6 run on handler2 and Buttons 7-9 run on handler3.  Handler2 and handler3 were both created on the main thread.

Answer (score 1):

It's impossible to say if it's the issue without testing it (preferably with some logging) but the only time `clicked9` seems to get reset is when you click the button and `clicked9` matches `req9`. But your runnable randomly sets `req9` to either *1* or *2*, so it's possible that this happens:

- `clicked9` is 0, `req9` is 2
- `onClick` increments `clicked9`, compares them
- `clicked9` is 1, `req9` is 2 - no match
- the Runnable updates `req9` to 1
- `onClick` increments `clicked9`, compares them
- `clicked9` is 2, `req9` is 1 - no match

Now you're in a situation where the next time button 9 is clicked, it'll increment to **3** - now it will never match `req9` which can never be higher than *2*. And because it never matches, it'll never be reset. It's permanently broken.

One way you could fix this is to do a validation check - `clicked9` should never be higher than 2, right? That third click should at the very least reset it, maybe trigger a penalty - but that last idea is complicated, because you seem to be switching buttons between "requires single click" and "requires double" randomly while they're active.

So if the player clicks at the wrong time, that "requires double" button they're double-clicking might turn into a single-click and suddenly that second click is a "mistake". So you'll have to decide on your game logic, and handle those "extra clicks" as appropriate. Just make sure it can never enter an invalid state!

---

By the way a `Handler` [is bound to a single thread](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler) so there's no such thing as "using too many threads" on one - it's just a message queue, you're not going to overload it!

Using a `Handler` based off the main thread is the easiest way to do what you're doing - if you start trying to add multithreading, you're introducing complexity and concurrency issues which will absolutely give you problems, and handling those correctly will make it even more complex.

So just do what you were originally doing, is my advice - use the main thread, post your runnables to its queue using a single handler, work out where your logic is tripping up with logging or debugging (so you can check the current variable values and see if anything's going wrong).

Comment: Thanks.  I think that fixed it.  I reset clicked to 0 for every button when resetting the colour to black.  Haven't had a malfunction since.